# How do I force a Windows Service to run synchronously instead of asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronous

I need to ensure `Thread.Sleep()` will actually run on my section of code due to API traffic speed limits to a third party API I'm hitting.  I figure the most reliable way to do this is to run the process Synchronously instead of Asynchronously - I've entertained the idea of System.Timer, CurrentThread, etc.

**QUESTION**: What's the most reliable way to ensure Thread.Sleep() prevents further execution of all processing, or in general, what's the most reliable way to pause execution of a Windows Service?  How do I ensure a process runs synchronously?

Comment: _I figure the most reliable way to do this is to run the process Synchronously_ - seems a bad idea all around. Control access to that API and let ASP/IIS do their stuff.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I guess I just don't follow - that's what I'm trying to do is control access to that API by essentially imposing a speed limit (no more than 3 calls per second).

Comment: It helps that you fixed the title but now it's unclear what the actual question is. What does 'hits' mean in _ensure Thread.Sleep() hits_ ? Is the Service receiving requests? Multithreaded? And the second para is still about ASP.NET.

Comment: @HenkHolterman My apologies, edited.

Comment: Now that the question has been completely rebuild, I guess the answer is: Use a System.Timers.Timer and don't start any threads you don't need.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks, it seems that using System.Timers has been the concensus between everyone I ask.  Thank you, if you want to post that as an official answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each request of any users to your asp.net app will run in its own thread. To synchronize that traffic you can create a singleton object and build a method which uses lock.
Lock will actually lock all threads out until the current thread finished.

So if you see the need to put a timeout, build a lock block and inside put a timeout.
Now all threads will have to wait...

Something like this

```
public class ThreadLock
{
    private static readonly object myLock;

    public void LockTimeout()
    {
        // --> first thread will trigger the following code. 
        // All other threads will wait 
        // <-- HERE 
        // until the first went through 
        lock (myLock)
        {
            //... do some timeout work
        }
    }
}
```

Anyways, I don't really get why you ever want to do something like this because usually we are all happy about having asynchronously working applications... anyways. Hope this helps

Comment: the reason is because I have to impose a speed limit to the API I'm calling (no more than 3 calls per second).  Async is great, but I'm trying to ensure that no more than 3 calls per second are exceeded.

Comment: This could work when used tightly around the API calls. But with 3 calls/second this site isn't going to scale well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The 3 calls per second is just populating my database.  I'm using the API to get the data I need to create the functional website I need.  So, I'll have this Windows Service running for maybe a month, by which time at the end my database will be populated with the relevant data from the API.  This is just an initial seeding.  User's will not experience this interaction.  What they'll experience is a direct interaction with the database I seeded from the API.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't want to get into specifics about what the site is or does, only to protect my idea.

Comment: I mean, thats fine. It is just another case where you need to pool your requests.
you'll still need to lock the threads comming in, but the logic to release the lock would then depend on how long one request or lets say, you have completed 3 requests in 300ms you'll have to wait 700ms until the next request will be served. I'd say, Thread lock would still do it for you

Comment: @MikeMarks - you've completely lost me.

Comment: @HenkHolterman seed the database means he populates his database with some static data after creating an empty database for example... This is usually a setup process while installing a new system.
So as I said, in this case, it doesn't matter if the site runs completly asynchronously or not. Just wondering why Mike would do this with a website, might be a better idea to write a small console app

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I have a layer of abstraction calling the third party API three times a second, and populating my SQL database.  This will run for as long as it needs to to get a fully populated database.  Once I have my SQL database populated, my website will call a different layer of abstraction to GET data from that SQL database.  Think of it as a diagram, from left to right: Third Party API <--> Windows Service <--> SQL Database <--> Web Service <--> Front End UI (Website).  The SQL Database is the hub in the diagram.  Hope that makes more sense, if it doesn't sorry..

Comment: @Ela Sorry, I didn't do a good job describing the architecture.  I'll have a Windows Service seeding my database, not an ASP.NET app.  THat's my bad, I revised the title.